# .live works when it shouldn't, and .bind doesn't work where it should

Tags: jquery, bind, live

I'm using this on an existing DOM element:

```
function questionsForm() {
    $("form[name='qc']:last").bind("focus", newTextLine);
}
```

and it doesn't work, but when i replace `.bind` with `.live` it works
this is the HTML where the handle is suppose to work:

```
    <body>

    <div id="screen">
        <div id="form">
            <div id="insertQuestions">
                <form id="qc" name="qc">
                <h2>Create New Question!</h2>
                <div id="question">Question: <input type="text" name="Question" /></div><!--question-->
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Why is it?
jQuery 1.6

Comment: jQuery 1.6, more chars to publish question.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`bind` only adds the event handler. and `trigger` runs it.

`live` both adds the handler and runs it

*side note*

Why dont you just select by the form's ID?

```
$("form#qc").bind("focus", newTextLine);
```

Comment: thier use described as the same: `$('selector').bind/.live("event", function)`

Comment: @IlyaD whats ur source for that?

Comment: @Neal, jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/bind, http://api.jquery.com/live

Comment: I see nothing in the doc for `bind` that says anything about `live`

Comment: @Neal, maybe I misunderstood, but you were saying I need to use something called `trigger` and I see nothing about it in the doc, it seems that the use pattern for `live` and `bind` is exactly the same, or am i wrong? and thanx for the ID tip

Comment: @Neal live doesn't run the handler, the bind and live functions are similar. The difference is that live works for all current and future elements that match the jquery selector while bind only works for elements that already exist.